# Why do my vocal recordings sound thin and muffled?

Tags: audio-recording

Hi there
i'm a newbie in recording so i have a beginners question:

I recently bought an Audio Interface (the M-Audio FastTrack Pro) and recorded some stuff, which was really fun, and seems to have gone well. But when I tried to record voice, I didn't get the sound I wanted to. I have to say that my microphone is not the best one, and I am not expecting the greatest results, but no matter what I tried, it was always a bit muffled, "small" and not clear enough. It was like you could hear that it was sung through a microphone and not just the voice (Ok thats a bad explanation, but that was the first thing I thought when listening to the recording)

So my question is, how can I improve my vocal recordings? Should I buy a better mic (it's a bit obvious that i should, but I don't really have the money)?

Comment: Welcome to Audio.SE :)  Don't worry about being a "beginner" - questions from all levels are welcome and we're all learning here.  What brand/model of microphone are you using?

Comment: see: http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/i-want-the-perfect-gun-sound-can-i-make-it-myself-any-tip-theory user `decasteljau` posts a link to an EA DICE video about recording audio. It is quite an eye opener the difference mike type and placement can have on a single sound

Comment: @Simil - What mic are you using now?

Comment: I'm currently using a stage dynamic mic by fame... But i'm currently searching for a decent Studio Mic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other factors other than the mic itself.

This [2001](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/nov01/articles/computervocals.asp) article, and another from [2004](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/mar04/articles/computervocals.htm), both from S-o-S, give some of the reasons (and solutions) for muffled, boxy recordings ... though their solutions are often reliant on further processing, e.g. compression, EQ, reverb.

Hopefully they'll provide useful background.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I would add to what's here is triple check your manual and make sure your settings are all correct.  Also, check your bit rate/sample rate settings.  Good luck!